# Upload file from vue.js to flask backend via Websocket

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I am looking for a minimal reproductible example on how to upload a file from Vue.js to flask backend  via websocket and saving it there. Preferably with the possibility to upload bigger files (few hundred MB)

the template:

```
    <template>
  <div>
  <form id='upload-form'>
    <input
      id='file-field'
      name='file'
      type='file' @change="onFileChange">
  </form>
      <button @click="uploadFile">Upload</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Vue script:

```
export default {
  name: "UploadFile",
  data () {
    return {
      file: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onFileChange (e) {
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (!files.length) {
        return
      }
      this.file = files;
    },

    uploadFile: function (e) {
      console.log('File upload clicked')
      this.$socket.emit('upload-file', this.file)
    }
  }
}
```

Flask:

```
# need to save file etc.
@socketio.on('upload-file')
def save_file(data):
    print("Data received")
    print(data)
```

Right now there is an error in flak on receiving the upload-file-event. The error appears regardless of the file size:

> message handler error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "~ib/python3.8/site-packages/engineio/server.py", line 549, in
> _trigger_event
> return self.handlersevent   File "~lib/python3.8/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 730, in
> _handle_eio_message
> if pkt.add_attachment(data):   File "~lib/python3.8/site-packages/socketio/packet.py", line 118, in
> add_attachment
> raise ValueError('Unexpected binary attachment') ValueError: Unexpected binary attachment

Comment: How big is your file? Also, note that you phrased your question as if you are doing file uploads with Flask, but this is all Socket.IO, so Flask has no participation in this.

Comment: Tested it for multiple file sizes ( 0 kb, 100kb, 50MB) , same error message

Comment: What is the type of `this.file`? Is this the actual data or a file object? You cannot emit a file object, you need to read your file and send the actual bytes.

Comment: ```typeof this.file``` returns "Object"

Comment: Can you log it to find out exactly what's in it?

Comment: ```this.file``` is of type ```filelist```, so just sending the first element ```this.file[0]``` removes the error and I receive bytes on the server-side